# How to sort on input text in Angular?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I am new to Angular. I have an input text box where I am going to enter sorting criteria like "rating" and "date". I have a controller defined with data.

```
comments: [{
    rating:5,
    date:"2012-10-16T17:57:28.556094Z"
},
{
    rating:4,
    date:"2014-09-05T17:57:28.556094Z"
}]
```

How can I define filters which will do the sorting based on input?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Working Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/QeNMPm1afQqVr0XXJOUI?p=preview)

In this example, when you type `rating` or `date` in input text field, it will sort the data based on this value. I have called the method on key press. If you want to sort after clicking on `sort` button, add a button and call he sorting method on `ng-click`.

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.controller('MyController',function($scope,$filter){
  $scope.test = 'This is a test!';

  $scope.comments = [
                           {
                               rating:5,
                               date:"2012-10-16T17:57:28.556094Z"
                           },
                           {
                               rating:4,
                               date:"2014-09-05T17:57:28.556094Z"
                           },
                           {
                               rating:7,
                               date:"2010-09-05T17:57:28.556094Z"
                           }]; 
  $scope.comments2 = $scope.comments;
  $scope.$watch('sortItem', function(val)
    { 

      if(val==='rating' || val==='date'){
         $scope.comments = $filter('orderBy')($scope.comments2,val);
      }
      else{
        return;
      }

    });                         

});
```

Hope that solve your problem.

Comment: I am adding an additional piece to work for desceding order. else if (val === '-rating' || val === '-date') {
      $scope.comments = $filter('orderBy')($scope.comments2, val, reverse); which didn't work. Could you correct me if I am wrong

Comment: actually . I found it. It sorts on $scope.comments = $filter('orderBy')($scope.comments2, val)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a collections library like underscorejs, and it will be like,

Bind your input box value to a variable as,

```
<select ng-model=inputVal></select>
```

Inside your controller function,

```
$scope.arr = _.sortBy($scope.originalArray, function(o) { 
    return o[$scope.inputVal]; 
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this process not working?

```
<div ng-app ng-controller="myCtrl">
<input type="text" ng-model="sortOption" />
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="comment in comments | orderBy: sortOption">
    rate: {{comment.rating}}
  </li>
</ul>
```

**AngularJS**

$scope.sortOption = "rating";

```
$scope.comments = [
                       {
                           rating:4,
                           date:"2015-10-16T17:57:28.556094Z"
                       },
                       {
                           rating:5,
                           date:"2014-09-05T17:57:28.556094Z"
                       }
                  ]
```

Answer (score 0):

In your controller add this:
           this.sortOption = ''

Call the sortOption above on your input text as follow:
ng-model="sortOption"

Finally modify your ng-repeat as follow:

ng-repeat="comment in YourControllerName.comments|orderBy: sortOption"
In a nutshell :if you type :date then it sorts by date. If you type author then it sorts by author, if you type rating then it sorts by rating.

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is to apply ng-model to your input to create a binding no need for ng-click. With two way data binding once the input field is touched the filter will be applied so:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="orderKey" name="orderField">
```

then using the repeat directive

```
ng-repeat = "comment in comments | orderBy:orderKey"
```

Pay attention to spacing between orderBy and the (:) NO SPACE